# How to zoom a imageview that was passed to bitmap

Tags: android, imageview, zooming, bitmapfactory

Hi every one am developing android applicaiton can someone tell me how can i zoom an imageview that was passed to bitmap.

### sample Code:

```
mColor_Img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.color_img_id);
Resources res = getResources();
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res,R.id.iv).copy(
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
mColor_Img.setImageBitmap(copy_bmp);
mColor_Img.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

Comment: Where is `copy_bmp` defined? Upon which event do you want to zoom the image (button press, double-tap, 'strech' e.g. on a specific gesture)?

Comment: copy_bmp defined globally and i want to zoom using pinch zoom.

Comment: And how does your `OnTouchListener` implementation look like? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think below link may help you :

[How to use Multi-touch in Android 2: Part 6, Implementing the Pinch Zoom Gesture](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-6-implementing-the-pinch-zoom-gesture/1847)